# Firestore - user favorites data structure suggestions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project where I need a user to be able to add items to his favorites like this:

```
Items 
 - Item 1 
 - Item 2
 - Item 3
Users
 - User 1
   - Favorites
     - Item 1
     - Item 3
 - User 1
   - Favorites
     - Item 2
```

Can anyone help by suggesting a good way to structure my data?

**EDIT 1:**

Sorry I should have explained this in the initial question. So I have a main list which shows all the items and their data from the database. Then each user has the ability to save an item he likes. After that on that user's page he should be able to view all the items he has saved.

Okay so far so good, but the only way I can think of to save the item in the user Favorites list is to save its ID there. Now there is a problem. I want to show the data of the item not just it's ID.

Comment: What's the problem with the structure you have in your question right now?

Comment: Looks like good to me. Why are you asking for another structure, what is wrong with that? Please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo I edited my post and explained it. Sorry about that

Answer (score 4):

> the only way I can think of to save the item in the user Favorites list is to save its ID there.

Yes, that's the best solution, to keep a reference of the item in the favorites list which is the actual item id.

> I want to show the data of the item not just it's ID.

In this case, you should query your database twice, once to get the the ids and then based on those ids to get the corresponding data. That's it. Don't be affraid about nested listeners, will work perfectly fine.

Comment: when we first fetch the ids list and then query for each id, it will be a lot of request not just two, is not it true?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan It will be two queries that will return a lot of possible documents. However, if the number of documents it's big, then you might consider getting them in smaller chunks.

Comment: what are you saying is when i fetch list of 10 ids and then run for loop to retrieve each id data that will consider as two queries?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan The operation for getting the IDs is considered a query, and the operation for getting the data that corresponds to those IDs is considered another query. However, you'll be billed according to the number of documents that you get from both queries.

Comment: Oh ok, i was thinking that we will be charged according to number of queries, what are you saying that we will be charged according to number of documents we fetched.